# Touch events in game object

Tags: actionscript-3, events, starling-framework

In my Starling game, the player sprite is controlled by clicking the screen where you want to go. Since (AFAIK) you can't have touch events that happen *outside* a sprite activate handlers in the sprite, I put the handlers in the game object. Here's a basic idea of how it goes:

To create my listener, I do this within my game object:

```
this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
```

But onTouch is never called (I even tried putting a `trace()` in there).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: With 1 line of code we can't do much to help you, that looks like a correct listener. What is a "Game" object? What does it inherit from? Should it be getting touch events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can make events that happen outside of a sprite to trigger the sprite's handlers, for this, you attach listeners not to the sprite, but to some other object, usually stage. Check if the stage is available, though. The best way to handle stage present is a listener to `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event. You put that into your handler object's constructor, and put all stage-aware code into that listener.

```
public function Handler() {
    if (stage) init(null); 
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}
private function init(e:Event):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    // entry point. This is where should stage-aware code start
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
    // at this point stage is populated and valid, thus we can use stage reference
    // without fear of null pointer.
}
```

Comment: Dammit, I was just about to submit a very large edit to my post. Anyway, it panics. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Yes. Add an `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event handler in the handler class, and put this code into the handler. I'm editing this to show how.

Comment: Thanks! It works and now I can continue to the other annoying bugs in my code.